# Sweet Alert en Modal Bootstrap

Tags: php, ajax, datatables, modal, sweetalert2

tengo el siguiente problema usando sweet alert y modal bootstrap.
Resulta, que hago las peticiones a traves de ajax y php, pero la alerta generada siempre me muestra el success independiente si la peticion al servidor fue exitosa o no. Lo que necesito es que si la peticion es exitosa, muestre el success, de lo contrario muestre error.
El codigo que dejo aqui, es como lo tengo ahora. He probado de muchas formas y no funciona ninguna y ademas me generaba errores, es por ello que solo escribo el success del procedimiento:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#edit_nomen').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var datos = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "miarchivo.php",
        data : datos,
        success:function(data){
            $('.modal').modal('hide');
            swal(
                'ALGUN TEXTO',
                'OTRO TEXTO',
                'success'
            );
            $('#respuesta').html(data);
            $('#listado').DataTable().ajax.reload();
        }
    });
});
});
```

Estoy usando SweetAlert2.
Esta demas mencionar, que este procedimiento se realiza sobre una ventana modal.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda u orientacion que puedan darme.
Saludos a todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que de seguro tienes un try catch en el servidor por lo que controlas los errores y regresa una respuesta sin problema. Mi solución es agregar una propiedad al Json retornado llamado respuesta que es un string que toma el valor de `"OK"` si completaron los procesos o toma el valor de la excepción.

Lo que hago para saber si la respuesta fue correcta simplemente hago una condicional en el success:

```
if(data.respuesta == "OK"){

// Peticion correcta
}
else{
// si se controla una excepcion en el servidor
alert(data.respuesta);
}
```

Teniendo en cuenta que **respuesta** es la propiedad que trae mi mensaje y **data** es todo el Json.

Comment: muchas gracias por responder. hare lo que me comentas y vere si puedo solucionarlo. gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Por nada recuerda se se completa la operación el string respuesta toma el valor de "OK" pero si entra al catch le pones el mensaje de la excepción.

Comment: perfecto, mas claro imposible. te comentare como me va. saludos y gracias nuevamente.